# Can I get symbol names from one .so and make another .so see it?

Tags: c++, linux, compilation, linker, shared-libraries

I've built *zlib* and *libpng* separately (what are these libs doesn't matter), so I've got libz.so and libpng.so now. With *dlopen()* and *dlsym()* I get function pointers from libpng.so and use them, but the problem is that, since libpng depends on zlib, I get linker errors when libpng function calls some zlib function inside itself. So my quiestion is: Is it possible to solve this problem without builing zlib with libpng together? Can I somehow get symbol names from zlib and make libpng see them?

P.S. I can't use dynamic linking because of the task.

Comment: Why do you want to use dlopen/dlsym rather than just linking with the libraries?

Comment: Just make sure you don't have circular dependencies.

Comment: I don't want to use dlopen/dlsym, but my teacher wants to :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found the solution. Just use **RTLD_GLOBAL** flag in dlopen and you'll be fine :)